# Express time elapsed between element of an array of date in hour min second using python

Tags: python, datetime, time, difference

I have a list of time creation of files obtained using os.path.getmtime

```
time_creation_sorted
Out[45]: 
array([  1.47133334e+09,   1.47133437e+09,   1.47133494e+09,
         1.47133520e+09,   1.47133577e+09,   1.47133615e+09,
         1.47133617e+09,   1.47133625e+09,   1.47133647e+09])
```

I know how to convert those elements in hour minute seconds.

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(time_creation_sorted[1]).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Out[62]: '09:59:26'
```

What I would like to do is to create another table that contains the time elapsed since the first element but expressed in hour:min:sec such that it would look like:

```
array(['00:00:00','00:16:36',...])
```

But I have not manage to find how to do that. Taking naively the difference between the elements of time_creation_sorted and trying to convert to hour:min:sec does not give something logical:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(time_creation_sorted[1]-time_creation_sorted[0]).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
Out[67]: '01:17:02'
```

Any idea or link on how to do that?

Thanks,
Grégory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearrange some parts of your code in order to get the desired output.

First you should convert the time stamps to `datetime` objects which differences result into so called `timedelta` objects. The `__str__()` representation of those `timedelta` objects are exactly what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

tstamps = [1.47133334e+09, 1.47133437e+09, 1.47133494e+09, 1.47133520e+09, 1.47133577e+09, 1.47133615e+09, 1.47133617e+09, 1.47133625e+09, 1.47133647e+09]
tstamps = [datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp) for stamp in tstamps]

tstamps_relative = [(t - tstamps[0]).__str__() for t in tstamps]
print(tstamps_relative)
```

giving:

```
['0:00:00', '0:17:10', '0:26:40', '0:31:00', '0:40:30', '0:46:50', '0:47:10', '0:48:30', '0:52:10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out timedelta objects, it gives difference between two dates or times

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects